# Cannot create a CV because "This location is not specific enough"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I decided to play around with the new Jobs beta, but I didn't get very far.  I clicked the "Jobs" tab on StackOverflow, and on the resulting page clicked the "Get started" button.  The next page had a box inviting me to "Start your developer CV", in which it auto-filled my name and location.  The latter was correct, and presented in the form <city>, <state>, United States.  When I clicked the "Continue" button in that box, however, the page presented a validation error:

> This location is not specific enough. You must provide at least the city you are currently in.

I tried a couple of alternatives for my location, including some suggestions presented on the drop-down list associated with the input field, but I never found one that the page would accept.

Comment: Curious - what location are you entering?

Comment: @JonH a galaxy, far, far away?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Would it be ok/correct if we returned that city a little west of you?

Comment: @JasonPunyon, that would be fine, but it is one of the alternatives I already tried.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Really? That isn't happening for me.

Comment: @JasonPunyon, except I just tried it again, and it worked.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: OK, we're on the same planet :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report, John Bollinger. I'll make it so that when someone comes in from your location next time it'll choose that better known city near you instead of the one we chose that doesn't work in our form.